# Configure PIMCore project version 6.7 on local windows environment XAMPP

Tags: redis, composer-php, pimcore

I am beginner in the PIMCore development and have a project of version 6.7,

My question is that what steps I have to follow to run/configure project on my local machine. Either command 'composer install' and then set 'document root' path in httpd.conf of xampp server is enough to run or I have to call 'pimcore install' as well after composer install. please guide.

1. Installed XAMPP
2. Installed PHP version 7.2 as per required by project composer.json file
3. Installed composer of version 1.0.0 as per mentioned in the composer.json file
4. Run 'php composer install' from command prompt inside of the project folder
5. Sets document root of the httpd.conf to the project/web folder

Getting following errors:
Once I adopt above steps and did installation as explained in my questions. Getting errors.

1. **In Admin panel**
   My site adminPanel displayed login screen properly but after getting
   login, no 'Documents', 'Assets and even 'Objects' are loaded in left
   side, after few seconds get error 'Server Threw exception- could not
   perform action. Please reload the admin interface and try again' In
2. **Client side Not loaded**, getting error

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in
D:\Pimcore\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php on line 129. Errors screenshots attached

[Admin Panel Error after logged in successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22fcR.png)
[Client side error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPUvj.png)

Comment: Why not read the installation instructions of that project? Is this question even related to programming?

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Pimcore 6.7 is horribly outdated (it was released in 2020!), PHP 7.2 is out of support since years, and Composer 1.0.0 is even older, it was released in 2016. All this pieces don't look like a good project setup

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase, for you reply, but my requirement is to retain same configuration as per defined in the project composer.json and composer.lock file because project is live and already working. I just want to configure it on my local machine and then need to make changes in it. 

composer.json:

"name": "pimcore/skeleton",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
    "pimcore/pimcore": "6.7.1",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
  },

Comment: Thanks @NicoHaase, for you reply, but my requirement is to retain same configuration as per defined in the project composer.json and composer.lock file because project is live and already working. I just want to configure it on my local machine and then need to make changes in it. 

composer.json:

"name": "pimcore/skeleton",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "ext-json": "*",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.2",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.7",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
    "pimcore/pimcore": "6.7.1",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^1.4"
  },

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, please share a **specific** question about all this. Anything not working with the given setup?

Comment: Once i adopt above steps and did installation as explained in my questions. Getting errors.

**In Admin panel**
My site adminPanel displayed login screen properly but after getting login, no 'Documents', 'Assets and even 'Objects' are loaded in left side, after few seconds get error **'Server Threw exception- could not perform action. Please reload the admin interface and try again'**

**In Client side**
Not loaded, got error 

Fatal error: **Maximum execution time of 240 seconds exceeded in** D:\Pimcore\project\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOStatement.php on line 129

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it**

Comment: @NicoHaase you please read my recent comment, I have added errors detail. secondly i have no idea how to edit my question, stackoverflow is only allowing me to add comments

Comment: Add all clarification to your question by editing it. That's possible through the "Edit" button above the comments ection. Also, if there is an error thrown by Pimcore, I would assume that the basic setup looks fine. You need to check **why** this error is thrown, but this problem does not look related to programming to me, thus it is off-topic on StackOverflow

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for your help, I have edited my question. It is programming error and i am looking for its solution. please help

Comment: If this really is a programming-related question, please share the code involved, along with your attempts to resolve the problem. Also, please adjust the tagging, or explain how the error message is related to Redis or Composer